# htaccess remove query string and then redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect a url based on query string and need to remove the query string on redirect.

> Source url: http://www.example.com/?id=15&L=1&link=androidapp
>
> Target url: http://www.example.com/test.php&id=15&L=1

'?id=' is a dynamic parameter. It is changed everytime.

I wrote following condition. It redirects, but I didn't get the desired target url.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} link=androidapp 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/test.php? [R=301,L]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Using that post I can redirect. But I didn't get the desired target url above. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: It just and always for `id=nnn&L=nnn` ?

Comment: Sorry. But the query string also exists with that. I need to strip the query string and need the target url like this : http://www.example.com/test.php&id=15&L=1 (Only with id and L parameters).

Comment: I understand that. My question the query string also exists always and only with `id=nnn&L=nnn` ?

Comment: Yes both id and L will always exists in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)&L=(\d+)&link=androidapp [NC]
RewriteRule ^ test.php?id=%1&L=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. One more doubt, is the "id" is append with "?" only? I mean "test.php?id". Can we cahnage this to "test.php&id" ?

Comment: You're welcome. No, you can't change that. The first (after .php or .htm), before query string is `?`, and between the elements it's `&`.